# Can deduced return type of member function be used as default argument value of a friend function template?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, friend, auto

In the program as follows, static function `A::f` has an automatically deduced return type. Despite it is defined in the code before its usage in default template parameter `class T = decltype(A::f())`:

```
struct A{
    static auto f() {}
    template<class T = decltype(A::f())>
    friend void g(A) {}
};

int main(){
    g(A{});
}
```

Clang refuses the program with the error:

```
function 'f' with deduced return type cannot be used before it is defined
```

while GCC is fine with the code, demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/5Tc879od8

Which compiler is right here?

Comment: Since `decltype(A::f())` is a valid type gcc seems to be right according to [temp.deduct](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.deduct#general-5).

Comment: I believe clang is correct. Class member functions are not defined until the close-brace of the class is reached. Otherwise their bodies wouldn't be able to reference members defined later in the class: `struct C { static auto f() { return m; } static int m; };` If functions were defined at the point of encounter, then f's body would be an error (no entity `m` exists yet).